# How to execute a command in Homebrew formula with post_install?

Tags: python, permissions, command, homebrew, superuser

I am building a homebrew for internal usage. The formula should do two things:

1. Install a python package
   => this works easily with `pip_install_and_build`.
2. Execute the just installed python tool to update/write in `.zshrc`.

=> The problem is I cannot run the function with permission, or I cannot even have permisssion to write in `.zshrc`.

I tried to either write directly in .zshrc or execute the python tool, but I always got `PermissionError: operation not permitted`). But these tool don't require sudo to do that.

On thing I noticed is that while the user is the same for both `.zshrc` and `/opt/homebrew/Cellar` (where the python tool is), group is `staff`for the former and `admin`for the  latter.

Is there any possibility to do what I would like? Could Homebrew asks a password to overwrite such permission?

Thank you for your help.